# How can one eliminate moiré artifacts from ListDensityPlot3D?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I’m having a hard time eliminating some moiré-like artifacts from the 3D output of `ListDensityPlot3D`.

Here is an example:

```
n = 1.5;
ρCore = 166;
bdElectronDensityConversion = 5.25*^23*ρCore;
ξCore = $MachineEpsilon;
R = 8.26*^9*Quantity["cm"];
M = 0.04*Quantity["SolarMass"];
K = (M^(1/3)*R*Quantity["GravitationalConstant"])/2.3573;
a = Sqrt[((n + 1)*(K*(ρCore*Quantity["g/cc"])^((1 - n)/n)))
         /(4*Pi*Quantity["GravitationalConstant"])];
ξRadius = (QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[R]]
               /QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[a]]);
system = {Dt[ξ^2*Derivative[1][θ][ξ], {ξ}]/ξ^2 == -θ[ξ]^n,
          θ[ξCore] == 1,
          Derivative[1][θ][ξCore] == 0};
sol = NDSolve[system, θ, {ξ, ξCore, ξRadius}][[1]];



Rkm = QuantityMagnitude@UnitConvert[R, "km"];
Show[DensityPlot3D[
    (bdElectronDensityConversion*θ[Sqrt[(x*ξRadius/Rkm)^2
    + (y*ξRadius/Rkm)^2 + (z*ξRadius/Rkm)^2]]^n /. sol),
    {x, y, z} ∈ RegionDifference[
        Ball[{0, 0, 0}, Rkm], Cuboid[{0, -Rkm, 0}, {Rkm, Rkm, Rkm}]], 
    PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", PlotPoints -> 100, 
    OpacityFunction -> None, 
    ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"SolarColors", {1*^25, 8*^25}}], 
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False], ImageSize -> Large]
```

When I run this code, I see this:
[image: Note moiré artifacts]

Sadly, moiré artifacts run throughout the cutaway faces of the ball, giving the false impression that a non-spherically-symmetric structure exists in the solution. This could mislead anyone hoping to interpret the plot!

I’d greatly appreciate any advice on eliminating these artifacts. I’ve tried increasing `PlotPoints`, to no avail.

Thanks!

Comment: How long does the graphic take to generate on your machine? (my question isn't related to the answer of your question, but I just let it run for a few minutes with no success... if it takes minutes to test each thing it might make the problem difficult to troubleshoot!)

Comment: Do you really need to use `ListDensityPlot` if you're only going to show a cutaway?  You can speed this plot by orders of magnitude by just plotting on the sphere surface and cutting planes.

Comment: @user6014: I’ve reduced `PlotPoints` to 100 in the example, since this still exhibits the moiré artifacts. It takes about 1 min 40 s to run on my machine.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork: That would help for this example, but sadly the full code includes a `ListDensityPlot3D` displaying data, which exhibits the same moiré artifacts. If you know of a comparable workaround for that case, however, it could be very helpful indeed.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this?:

```
MapAt[
 Rotate[#, -2 Pi/3, {1, 1, 1}] &@Scale[#, {1, -1, 1}] &, 
 SliceDensityPlot3D[(bdElectronDensityConversion*θ[
         Sqrt[(x*ξRadius/Rkm)^2 + (y*ξRadius/
               Rkm)^2 + (z*ξRadius/Rkm)^2]]^n /. x -> -x /. sol) //
    Evaluate, {"CenterCutSphere"}
  , {z, -Rkm, Rkm}, {x, -Rkm, Rkm}, {y, -Rkm, Rkm},
  ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"SolarColors", {1*^25, 8*^25}}], 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, AxesLabel -> RotateLeft@{z, x, y}
  ],
 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Unfortunately, `"CenterCutSphere"` is a cut with respect to the azimuthal angle only, so conjugation by some geometric transformations is necessary.